# How to convert mysqli_query to PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code and was wondering how to convert it to PDO statement, once mysqli_query is old fashion.

Api.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
if (isset($_GET['order_id']) && $_GET['order_id']!="") {
include('db.php');
$order_id = $_GET['order_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE order_id=$order_id");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$amount = $row['amount'];
$response_code = $row['response_code'];
$response_desc = $row['response_desc'];
response($order_id, $amount, $response_code,$response_desc);
mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    response(NULL, NULL, 200,"No Record Found");
    }
}else{
response(NULL, NULL, 400,"Invalid Request");
}

function response($order_id,$amount,$response_code,$response_desc){
$response['order_id'] = $order_id;
$response['amount'] = $amount;
$response['response_code'] = $response_code;
$response['response_desc'] = $response_desc;

$json_response = json_encode($response);
echo $json_response;
}
?>
```

db.php

```
<?php

// Enter your Host, username, password, database below.
// I left password empty because i do not set password on localhost.
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","allphptricks");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
    }
?>
```

I am new in PHP and couldn't do it by myself. If you need more details, let me know. Can someone help?

Comment: `mysqli_query` isn't old fashion, it is just insecure and only compatible with `mysql`. You can use prepared statements with `mysqli` almost as easily as PDO. Can you please share what you've tried with PDO and issues you ran into?

Comment: Hello, thats the thing, i dont know even how to start :(

Comment: Perhaps, like this?

 $result = $db->prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE order_id=$order_id");

Comment: Need to make a PDO connection first https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php. Also, again, PDO alone does nothing. The above statement would be just as insecure. You need to parameterize the queries with prepared statements. `mysqli` supports prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get a PDO connection to your database like this - replacing all uppercase values in the first 5 lines below with your values:

```
    $host    = DATABASE_HOST;
    $dbase   = DATABASE_NAME;
    $user    = DATABASE_USER;
    $pass    = DATABASE_PASS;
    $charset = DATABASE_CHARSET;

    // set the connection parameters
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbase;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    // get the connection
    $this->pdb = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Then you can use the statements below to read and write the database:

```
// WRITE STATEMENT THAT RETURNS ROW ID
$stmt = $this->pdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($fields);
$retval = $this->pdb->lastInsertId();

// READ STATEMENTS

$stmt = $this->pdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($fields);

// fetches one field
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); 

// fetches multiple fields
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Here is a link to a great PDO guide
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: `printf("PDO Get Connection failure: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());` looks a bit awkward...

Comment: Thanks for correcting that.  I cut and pasted more than I should have.  Leftovers from old code.